# How to plot a boxplot of single column using plotnine in python without any grouping?

Tags: plotnine

This is mt cars data-set.
I want to plot the box-plot of mpg column, we also have to specify x aesthetic if we are not it is showing error

```
(
    ggplot(cars,aes(y='mpg',x=))+geom_boxplot()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply a dummy value for `x`:

```
( ggplot(mtcars,aes(y='mpg',x=0))+geom_boxplot() )
```

Comment: can you tell what is happening under the hood when we write x=0